# how to read and edit a doc file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a .doc or .docx file where in after the booking of the hotel room i wanna give the agreement and the receipt in a .doc file.
for this i have a text file,

> To, [**NAME**] 
>       
> [**ADDRESS**]
>
> Dear....
>
> ...Content;;;...

This will be my .doc file. My idea is to read this .doc file and replace the tags, say.([**NAME**] and [**ADDRESS**]) with the user's name and address.

How can i do this in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Define your NAME and ADDRESS tags as form fields in the doc and use VSTO to open the doc, find the form fields, and replace the text.

Another third party tool you can use for manipulating office documents is Aspose.  It is useful in that it doesn't require an install of Office to work with office documents.

Comment: @BigChrisDiD: -1 for suggesting the use of VSTO in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @Nimesh: _what_ was your mistake? My comment means that _I_ voted -1.

Comment: Yes sorry, was rushing.  Nimesh, Aspose is a third party product you need to buy a licence for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not use COM Interop directly or indirectly to call on Word from an ASP.NET application. It's unsupported, usually doesn't work well, and has licensing implications as well.

The Office products are made to be desktop applications. They do not work when run from a service.

Comment: so what is the best that i can do.... i was trying with th way that ratty told. but that is giving some strange behaviour. i am able to read the file but that contains 
�����������������������.

Comment: @Nimesh: I've heard people say they like the "Aspose" products. They do all their work on their own, without calling on Word.

Comment: Does Aspose require's licence?
What is the solution that you can give to me...? so that i can start working on that.. Is there any other way around in achieving my requirement?